# What is the difference between line cards and fabric cards in a CISCO NCS 6000?

Tags: cisco, router, line-card

I was reading the site preparation guide for the Cisco NCS 6000 Series routers and I saw this line:

"The Cisco NCS 6000 Series Routers include the Cisco NCS 6008 Line Card Chassis (LCC) and the Cisco NCS 6000 Fabric Card Chassis (FCC)."

Are those part of the same machine? What's the difference between fabric and line cards?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

The NCS6k is designed to operate as both a stand-alone chassis, as well as connect to a separate chassis that holds only switch fabric cards.  As a standalone system, the switch fabric still interconnects all the linecards, but the fabric cards are on the "back" of the chassis and have only internal-facing interfaces.

In a multi-chassis system you have a set of "linecard chassis" that all interconnect through a different set of fabric cards to the "fabric chassis".

Essentially, the fabric chassis allows you to build an even larger system than you could with a single chassis of 8 linecards.

Answer (score 0):

A LCC is a Chassis that places the Line Cards (MSC, FP), PLIM's, etc. A FCC is the one where the whole Fabric Cards are installed (FC). There's a nice explanation regarding Multi-Chass on following blog-post:

http://ccie49534.com/2015/11/05/cisco-crs-multi-chassis/

Answer (score -1):

FCC is like a big "card" that can have other more little LCC cards inside. You have a good explanation [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/crs/crs1/mss/16_slot_fc/system_description/reference/guide/sysdesc/msssd1.html#pgfId-1047176)